# Do you think OSGi has a solid future in enterprise apps, or it is going to fade away like the whole ESB thing appears to be?

Tags: osgi, soa, esb

As per title. I don't know if this is the right place or way to ask this, admins feel free to edit/move/close the question if appropriate.

I'd like to get pointers to recent material clarifying the market trends, as well as real life examples. Even pseudo-pundit, Gartner-like stuff is OK. Thanks.

Comment: Given that OSGi has been around for 10+ years, that Eclipse now uses it at its core, and just about every major app-server is now build on it, I don't see it disappearing anytime soon.  Job demand stats just show volatility http://www.itjobswatch.co.uk/jobs/uk/osgi.do over the last few years.  Trends come and go, real solutions persist - IMO OSGi is the latter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am curious about the second part of the question. What is the basis of your statement that 'the ESB thing' appears to be fading? I don't believe it is.

The problem with ESBs however is that some vendors call their product an ESB, but it actually is much much more than that. In some companies this happened with their  integration product just because Gartner or some other analysts company says that ESB is hot. Marketing strategy is changed: The product is called ESB and maybe somethings are added that are expected in an ESB. 
Paul Fremantle of WSO2 wrote a very good article about what an ESB really is [1].

As for OSGi: The first company I saw using it in their middleware was WSO2. I have heard, that TIBCO, another middleware vendor, is also moving or has moved towards using it in their Active Matrix platform. 
OSGi may help in various ways. The most important is that it decreases the effort of the installation of the platform. Install a minimum on each system used to deploy the application, and during deployment the components required to run the application will be added. You do not have to worry about having installed the right plug-ins, add-ons and what not. This is what both WSO2 and TIBCO are doing. 
With some vendors, you see that you need to install an awful amount of software, of which you in the end may be using just a small part (e.g. IBM WebSphere). Because of this, you may have to use over-dimensioned systems, which adds extra costs.

OSGi may prevent this. 
Have a look at the presentation of WSO2 about the WSO2 Carbon platform [2].
The statement at the end of the presentation says it all:

> *Adapt the middleware to your architecture, **not** the architecture to the middleware*

**So yes, I think OSGi has a future in enterprise apps.**

[1] http://wso2.org/library/2913

[2] http://www.slideshare.net/wso2.org/the-carbon-story-presentation-855666

Disclaimer: 
I am in no way affiliated with WSO2, TIBCO or IBM. I am a certified TIBCO BusinessWorks Developer and have been developing applications for the IBM WebSphere Process Server platform. Above all, I am a WSO2 Enthusiast.

Comment: Funny that you mention WebSphere in the negative since it is, built on OSGi as well, along with many other appservers.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi#Projects_using_OSGi

Comment: I mentioned it in the negative, since a WebSphere installation takes hundreds of megabytes, even on the server where you will deploy the application.
I also made an assumption (yeah, kinda dangerous) about how OSGi would be used in an enterprise. From my answer you can see what my thoughts are when it comes to using OSGi in the enterprise. The fact that it is used in WebSphere does not have anything to do with that.

Answer (score 2):

I would say yes..WSO2 has proof for that..Check the following links

http://osgi.dzone.com/articles/carbon-osgi-and-soa

http://www.infoworld.com/d/developer-world/wso2-upgrades-osgi-middleware-695